# Assigning price declared in one list to item from other list and count total price - Python

Tags: python

I have two list one-dimensional. 
One is storing pizza available in my menu. 
Second is storing prices for this pizzas.

But I don't know, how to assign this prices for each pizza and also, if user selected for example pizza "Margerita" my program must know that Margherita costs for example 15 dollars and after this choice, program can print total amount to pay for pizzas. Please do not pay attention to pizzeria drinks i only need to solve problem with pizzas.

````
pizzeria_menu = ['Margherita', 'Capricossa', 'Salami', 'Wiejska']
pizzeria_drinks = ['Pepsi', 'Mirinda', 'Sprite']
pizza_prices = [20, 15, 25, 30]

def clientOrders():

    pizzeria_orders = []

    clientPizzaChoice = input('\nJaka pizza dla Ciebie? ')

    clientDrinkChoice = input('Jakis napoj do tego? ')

    if clientPizzaChoice in pizzeria_menu and clientDrinkChoice in pizzeria_drinks:
        pizzeria_orders.append(clientPizzaChoice)
        pizzeria_orders.append(clientDrinkChoice)
        print('Zamawia pan pizze: ' + clientPizzaChoice + ' i napoj ' + clientDrinkChoice + '.')

    elif clientPizzaChoice in pizzeria_menu and clientDrinkChoice not in pizzeria_drinks:
        print('Zamowil pan tylko pizze: ' + clientPizzaChoice + '.')
        pizzeria_orders.append(clientPizzaChoice)

    elif clientPizzaChoice not in pizzeria_menu and clientDrinkChoice in pizzeria_drinks:
        print('Zamowil pan tylko napoj: ' + clientDrinkChoice + '.')
        pizzeria_orders.append(clientDrinkChoice)

    else:
        print('Bardzo nam przykro, ze nic Pan nie zamowil. :(')  
clientOrders()```
````

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a dictionary, e.g. `{"Margherita": 20}`, etc? That would make your life a lot easier I think

Comment: Are you forced to use a **list** or can you use a different data structure? it seems like a **dict** would be more appropriate.

Comment: @BenjaminBreton yes i'm forced cause i'm beginner and i need to understand lists. Now i'm on this episode on my course and I really want to learn it.  And also  it's answer for your question. patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really neeed to use lists, you can use the `index()` method of list: see [data structure doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

```
pizzeria_menu = ['Margherita', 'Capricossa', 'Salami', 'Wiejska']
pizza_prices = [20, 15, 25, 30]

clientpizza = input("Order you pizza, please: ")

try:
    idx = pizzeria_menu.index(clientpizza)
    price = pizza_prices[idx]
    print("Your pizza {} costs {:d}".format(clientpizza, price)) 
except ValueError:
    print("Pizza not in the menu")
```

or if you prefer an `if` statement instead of the `try` `except` block:

```
if clientpizza in pizzeria_menu:
    idx = pizzeria_menu.index(clientpizza)
    price = pizza_prices[idx]
    print("Your pizza {} costs {:d}".format(clientpizza, price)) 
else:
    print("Pizza not in the menu")
```

list index method:

> Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is x. Raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

So this works fine under the assumption that there are not repeated values in the list.
For example, `pizzeria_menu.index('Salami')` returns `2`, as 'Salami' is the element at position 2 (indexing starts from 0).

`price = pizza_prices[idx]` this is basic indexing, it returns the element of the list at position `idx`.
For example, `pizza_prices[2]` is `25`.

You should be able to adapt this to your code.

Comment: So this  idx = pizzeria_menu.index(clientpizza) finding if value which user wroted in input is in pizzeria_menu list, yes?

Comment: It returns the position (index) of the element in the list. In my example, if you input "Capricossa" will return 1 (that is, idx is 1). Try to add `print(idx)` just after the statement and you will see.

Comment: Thank you very much i changed it for "if statement" and it works

Comment: And price =pizza_prices[idx] here u created one more list which is storing index of pizza but how price is assigned to this index i dont really understand...

Comment: `price =pizza_prices[idx]` This does not create a list. It returns the element of pizza_prices` at index `idx`. Let me edit the question to add more details.

Comment: Ahh okay i understand.  I didn't know that was indexing. Now i understand all.  Thanks for great explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you must use lists, I can see two ways to do this:

1. using a **List of Tuples**

```
pizzeria_menu = [('Margherita', 20), ('Capricossa', 15), ...]
```

You can fill this list of tuples with a for loop, and retrieve the price of an item using a **for loop** as well, this could also work using a list of lists.

2. using the **index**

By using the **enumerate** function, you could find the index where your pizza is stored in the **pizza_menu** and use the value of the index to retrieve its price.

```
pizzeria_menu = ['Margherita', 'Capricossa', 'Salami', 'Wiejska']
pizza_prices = [20, 15, 25, 30]

pizza_to_find = "Margherita"
pizza_ix = -1

for ix, pizza_name in enumerate(pizzeria_menu):
  if pizza_name == pizza_to_find:
    pizza_ix = ix

price_to_find = pizza_prices[pizza_ix]
```

Comment: Okay good, but how can i do it without loops but with tuples? is it possible? I know i can make my life easier but this time for me i want do without for loop.

Comment: You can do it with a comprehension list (which is not exactly a loop).